# Nginx Path with Multiple Masks

Tags: nginx

I have a url directory path `localhost/storage/app/media`

I need it to be masked with both `localhost/v/` and `localhost/i/`.

**Nginx Sites-Available**

This works for `/v/`, but if I make the same rules with `/i/` it conflicts and shows a blank page with the message `File not found.` on all pages of the site.

```
# Mask storage media directory with /v/
rewrite ^/v(.*)$ /storage/app/media$1 last;

# Mask storage media directory with /i/
rewrite ^/i(.*)$ /storage/app/media$1 last;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your regular expression more specific. At the moment you are matching anything that begins with an `i`, for example, `index.html`. Try:

```
rewrite ^/v(/.*)$ /storage/app/media$1 last;
rewrite ^/i(/.*)$ /storage/app/media$1 last;
```